# YA science fiction about a post-apocalyptic Earth, featuring island-like city states connected by walkways

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, post-apocalyptic

This is a YA science fiction novel I read more than a decade ago. I can remember a few details. AFAIK there were no sequels, so interest in it eventually petered out but I want to check up on it again.

So the bare details are: post-apocalyptic Earth. Almost all land is submerged in an ocean, as told to protagonist. There are a few city-states which are built on the ocean (the habitable parts sticking out of the ocean, not submerged), like islands. Each city-state focuses on specific occupations and are connected by walkways/causeways.

The hero, a teenager, finds a young girl, who is being aggressively pursued by several factions. There is a spider-like monster which is locked up but is released and kills several people. A lot of internal strife going on which results in the death of the leaders in the end.

One fact stands out- the leaders actually processed the flesh of the people who died and fed it to the population, thus keeping everyone hunger-free, but this was a big secret. The hero, along with the girl sets off across the ocean on a boat for mythical land.

Any tips on which book/author it was would be very helpful

Comment: So, Soylent Green meets Waterworld...

Comment: Somewhat... but its not Soylent Green

Comment: Any tips, anyone?

Comment: Any tips ? The author is/was quite famous, and this was sort of side project, but I liked it

Comment: The only thing I can think of is _[The Blue World](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40874.The_Blue_World)_ by Jack Vance, but too many things don't fit.

Comment: You are right, it isn't. But this seems interesting too. Thanks for the attempt